# Minimum RAM for a simple ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know it depends, but I am just curious what specifications others are using to run a simple site with a MS SQL Server back-end. What is recommended for the application, not the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not talking about the database, I would say that running a simple MVC web application you would just need enough RAM to run whatever Windows OS you plan on deploying it under.  You shouldn't need any more than the recommended amount.

So for example, here are the [Windows Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/system-requirements.aspx) requirements.

Comment: which would be better: 1 (1gbRAM) machine with sqlexpress and asp application OR 2 machines at .5RAM app and db separate computers?

Comment: I think separating a the database and app into separate machines would only gain you more of a security advantage rather than performance. Unless your app is performing very large queries.

Comment: @zsharp for a simple app?  I would say one machine, as James has indicated.  However, for larger apps, you're going to need to scale, and that means you'll need to tier out your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Would have to agree with Joe, the recommended RAM for running the OS should be sufficient. However, when you start to use resource hungry tools like SQL Server I would always recommend adding at least 1 GB.

Comment: @James Totally Agree.  When you slap on SQL Server into the mix you're talking about a completely different kind of memory footprint needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a simple MVC site on Windows XP with IIS 5.1 and SQL Server 2005 Express.  [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314865) are the system requirements for Windows XP.

RAM is so cheap now I would go with at least 2 GB.